# Object reference not set to an instance of an object, parameter is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I am having issues with passing an argument from my view to my controller

I have this code fragment in my view:

```
<a class="btn-simple" onclick="submitDetails('Dashboard', 'Cancel', '<%=Model.Data.Id %>', $('form'));">save</a>
```

and this is from my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Cancel(string id, FormCollection collection)
{
       var appt = Application.Session.GetObjectFromOid<Appointment>(new ObjectId(id));
}
```

I get an error saying that "id" is null, but when I test Model.Data.Id in the view, it is not null.

And this is my submitDetails function:

```
function submitDetails(controller, method, id, form) {
    form.ajaxSubmit({ target: '#itemdetails' });

}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is getting back to my controller from a button in the view, the "[HttpPost]" version of the method that originally called the view

Comment: Please post the `submitDetails()` code.

Comment: What does `submitDetails` do?

Comment: because your just passing id back as a string. The string doesn't know the same things your model knows.  In this case it is looking for id as part of the url string i.e. controller/view/id. you have to pass the id from the model.

Comment: I am very new at this so I might not be doing what I am trying to do at all. I just want to get to the [HttpPost] version of Cancel() when I press the "Save" Button

Comment: `<%=Model.Data.Id %>` - Are you sure `Model.Data` isn't null?

Comment: I am sure, just to be sure I printed it in my view

Comment: what about passing the model with tempdata then you will have the original state and when you hit cancel you can call that tempdata to populate the page.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the form you are submitting contains a hidden field with the id or it is passed as query string parameter:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Dashboard", "Cancel", new { id = Model.Data.Id })) { %>
    ...
<% } %>
```

or if you want to pass a dynamic url you could do the following:

```
<a class="btn-simple" onclick="submitDetails('<%= Url.Action("Dashboard", "Cancel", new { id = Model.Data.Id }) %>', $('form'));">save</a>
```

and then:

```
function submitDetails(url, form) {
    form.ajaxSubmit({ url: url, target: '#itemdetails' });
}
```

---

UPDATE:

And if you want to avoid the `submitDetails` javascript method and have your anchor be the submit button of the form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Dashboard", "Cancel", new { id = Model.Data.Id })) { %>
    ...

    <button class="btn-simple" type="submit">save</button>
<% } %>
```

Comment: I would like to avoid using submitDetails altogether if that is possible

Comment: @user1229309, in this case you could make this anchor be the submit button for your form. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: then you can add a hidden field as DD suggested with the value of model.data.id and grab that in the form collection.  <input type="hidden" id="id" value="<%Model.Data.Id%>" />

Comment: @user1229309, how does the action attribute of the form look like? Does it contain the id? Like for example `action="/Dashboard/Cancel/123"`?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I dont know what you mean by the action attribute

Comment: @user1229309, the `<form>` tag that is generated by the Html.BeginForm helper in the resulting HTML has an `action` attribute. So look at the generated HTML.

Comment: @user1229309, well, that's your problem. This means that `Model.Data.Id` is probably null or empty.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I originally had this <form name="create" id="create" action="/Manage/Dashboard/Cancel/" method="post"> in my view, should I not include that?

Comment: @once I comment that out and let a form be generated on its own, the id is in the action attribute, but I get this erro HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. r:

Comment: @user1229309, I see that the url being generated contains an area prefix: `Manage`. Is this correct? Are you using areas? Does the DashBoard controller belong to some area or is it in the root? Also as I already said multiple times, you must send a valid integer as id along with the request. Check with your routes and check that your url is valid and contains the id.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov yes, I am using Areas, and Manage is correct. Model.Data.Id is a string, not an integer and is not null. the url is /Manage/Cancel/Dashboard/67eecb03759d452011000000 when I press save. The error is different than before. It says that the resource cannot be found

Comment: I think I solved it, thank you so much for you help. I added <%-Model.Data.Id%> to the action in my form